# Does every triangle satisfy $a^c + b^c - c^c < \pi$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, inequality, triangles, maxima-minima

Let $(a,b,c)$ be the sides of a triangle and let its circumradius be $1$. Is it true that

$$
a^c + b^c - c^c < \pi
$$

**My progress**: In the special case where at least two of the three sides are equal, I have been able to show that the upper bound is about $3.13861$. If two sides are equal and the third side is $c = x$ then the length of the two equal side are $a = b = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4-x^2}}$ each. Maximizing the expression using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=maximize%202%28sqrt%282%20%2B%20sqrt%284%20-%20x%5E2%29%29%29%5Ex%20-%20x%5Ex%20%2C%200%20%3C%3D%20x%20%3C%3D%202)

$$
2\left(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4-x^2}}\right)^x - x^x
$$

gives $3.13861$ as the upper bound in this case. Further more, simulation show that this is also the unconditional maxima but I have not been able to prove it. Since $3.13861$ is very close to $\pi$ so, I expressed the above inequality in terms of $\pi$ to present it in an elegant form but it seems the proximity is just a coincidence unless I am missing something.

Comment: I'm entirely convinced that the proximity is just a coincidence. Letting $R=1$ WLOG eliminates it from the expression entirely and now all the circle does is set an upper bound for the side lengths, i.e. $a,b,c\leq2$. The resulting $a^{c}+b^{c}-c^{c}$ does not look like it would be bounded by a transcendental like $\pi$.

Answer (score 4):

The three vertices of any such triangle can be taken to be on the unit circle; without loss of generality, one of them can always be $(1,0)$. Therefore the entire configuration space of triangles can be parametrized by two angles $x$ and $y$, with the other two vertices being $(\cos x,\sin x)$ and $(\cos y,\sin y)$. This is a very reasonable numerical optimization problem, and Mathematica finds the maximum value to be about $3.1386122590888217$ when $x=-1.5106639429716202$ and $y=2.3862607049785898$, which is to say when the three vertices are
$(1,0)$, $(0.060096151557482914, -0.9981925929238206)$, and $(-0.728044022440954, 0.6855303796244158)$. (The lengths of the sides of this triangle are $1.8590556694615026$, $1.8590556863316139$, and $1.3710607925562726$, so perhaps the optimal triangle is really isosceles and the accuracy isn't as good as the decimal places indicate.) I strongly suspect that the maximum value is some random transcendal number having nothing to do with $\pi$ or any other constant we've ever seen.

Comment: I guess technically the answer is yes, since $3.1386...$ is indeed less than $\pi$, haha.

Answer (score 3):

**Some thoughts.**

The conditions are given by
$$0 < a, b, c \le 2, \quad a + b > c, \quad b + c > a, \quad c + a > b,$$
$$R = \frac{abc}{\sqrt{(a + b + c)(a + b - c)(b + c - a)(c + a - b)}} = 1. \tag{1}$$

Since $x \mapsto x^{c/2}$ is concave, we have
$$a^c + b^c = (a^2)^{c/2} + (b^2)^{c/2}
\le 2 \left(\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}\right)^{c/2}. \tag{2}$$

From (1), we have
$$(abc)^2 = (a + b + c)(a + b - c)(b + c - a)(c + a - b)$$
and thus
$$(a^2 + b^2 - c^2)^2 = a^2b^2(4 - c^2)
\le \frac{(a^2 + b^2)^2}{4}(4 - c^2)$$
which results in
$$a^2 + b^2 \le 4 + 2\sqrt{4 - c^2}. \tag{3}$$

Using (2) and (3), we have
$$a^c + b^c - c^c 
\le 2\Big(2 + \sqrt{4 - c^2}\Big)^{c/2} - c^c.$$

Let $f(c) := 2\Big(2 + \sqrt{4 - c^2}\Big)^{c/2} - c^c$.
Numerical experiments show that
the maximum of $f(c)$ on $[0, 2]$ is near $3.13861$ when $c$ is near $1.371$.
Numerical experiments also show that $f$ is concave on $[0, 2]$.
Thus, the maximum occurs at $f'(c) = 0$.